# MongoDB aggregation transformation

Tags: mongodb, redash

I have a MongoDB, which is used in *Redash* to query some data. For a Funnel i want to display via Redash i have a MongoDB query that results in something like this

```
X   Y   Z
20  10  35
```

But actually the Funnel Chart in Redash requests a table that looks like

```
State  Value
X      20
Y      10
Z      35
```

How can i extend my MongoDB aggregation to get the wanted result? Maybe just manually create the needed rows? How to do that?

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution?